# Why is the weak topology defined on cell complexes equivalent to the topology defined by the quotient map?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Just for background, I have been reading from Hatcher's textbook where he defines a cell complex in the following way:

> **(1)** Take any discrete set $X^0;$ we will call each element in this set a $0\textrm{ -}$cell.

> **(2)** Let $\varphi_\alpha:S^{n-1}\rightarrow X^{n-1}$ be some collection of maps. Construct a quotient space $X^n$ of the space $X^{n-1}\bigsqcup_\alpha \mathbb{D}_\alpha^n$ by the relation $\sim$ defined as $x\sim \varphi_\alpha(x)$ for each $x\in\partial\mathbb{D}_\alpha^n.$ The space $X^n$ is called the *$n\textrm{ -}$skeleton*, and this process is described as attaching $n\textrm{ -}$cells $e_\alpha^n$ through the maps $\varphi_\alpha.$ Hence, we can write $X^n=X^{n-1}\bigsqcup_\alpha e_\alpha^n,$ where $\{e_\alpha^n\}$ is some collection of open $n\textrm{ -}$cells.

> **(3)** Finish the construction by stopping the inductive process for some $n$ and let $X=X^n$ or let process go on infinitely and set $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X^n;$ we give the space the weak topology defined as $$\mathcal{T}=\{A\subseteq X:A\cap X^n\textrm{ is open in } X^n,\textrm{ for all }n\}.$$

I have questions on the topology defined above in a finite case, that is, when $X=X^n;$ for the quotient map  $q:Y\rightarrow Y/\sim,$ from any topological space $Y$ into $Y/\sim,$ the quotient space,  we define the quotient topology to be the collection of sets $\mathcal{U}=\{A\subseteq Y/\sim:q^{-1}(A) \textrm{ is open in } Y\}.$ I don't see how these two definitions, that is the **(3)** and the quotient topology are equivalent; we would need to prove that for $A\subseteq X$ and each $0\leq i\leq n,$ $$q^{-1}(A) \textrm{ is open in } X^{n-1}\bigsqcup_\alpha\mathbb{D}_\alpha^n \Longleftrightarrow X^{n-i}\cap A \textrm{ is open in } X^{n-i}.$$
Now, if $q^{-1}(A)$ is open in the original space, the implication easily follows; I don't see it forming in the opposite direction, **why does it follow that if $X^{n-i}\cap A$ is open in $X^{n-i}$ where $0\leq i\leq n$ imply that $q^{-1}(A)$ is open in the original space?**

Comment: Writing $q : X \to X / \sim$ makes no sense. For each $n$ we have a different relation $\sim$ on $X^{n-1} \coprod_\alpha \mathbb D^n_\alpha$, and it's quotient space is defined to be $X^n$ (since these are distinct relations it's perhaps better to index them by $n$ and write $\sim_n$). However, in this discussion there is no relation on $X$ and no quotient space of $X$, instead $X$ is the last object in the sequence of quotients.

Comment: Perhaps instead you meant to write $q : X_{n-1} \to X_{n-1} / \sim_n = X$ (using my notation for $\sim_n$)?

Comment: I was actually just writing the definition of a quotient topology for a general space $X$... I see that may be confusing, I will change that. Also, yes in this specific case, your defintion would be the way to go yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hatcher describes how CW-complexes are constructed:

1. Start with a set $X^0$ having the discrete topology.
2. Construct inductively skeleta $X^n$ by attaching $n$-cells to $X^{n-1}$. Here $X^{n-1}$ already has a topology and $X^n$ is defined as a suitable quotient space of $X^{n-1}\bigsqcup_\alpha \mathbb{D}_\alpha^n$.

This construction produces a sequence of spaces $X^0, X^1, X^2,\ldots$ such that $X^{n-1}$ is a *subspace of $X^n$*.

If this process stops at some finite $N$, then we have a topology on $X = X^N$. In that case *trivially* $A  \subset X$ is open iff $A \cap X^n$ is open in $X^n$ for all $n$. Just note that $X^n = X$ for $n \ge N$.

If the attaching process continues ad infinitum, then we have a topology on each skeleton $X^n$, and these toplogies are *compatible* in the sense that $X^{n-1}$ is a subspace of $X^n$ for each $n$. Howewer, we **do not** have a topology on $X = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X^n$. That is why we give the space $X$ the weak topology defined as in (3). This definition is relevant *only in case that the attaching process continues ad infinitum*.

**Edited on request:**

Suppose we have an ascending sequence of topological spaces $X^0, X^1, X^2,\ldots$ (*ascending* means that for all $n > 0$ we have $X^{n-1} \subset X^n$ and that the topology on $X^{n-1}$ is the subspace topology inherited from $X^n$). Then let $X = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X^n$. Which topology do we introduce on $X$ in order that all subspaces $X^n$ receive their original topology? In general there are many ways to do that, but the *standard approach* is to define $A \subset X$ open in $X$ iff $A \cap X^n$ is open in $X^n$ for all $n$. This is the *final topology* with respect to the system $\{X^n\}$. In the context of CW-complexes it is also denoted as the *weak topology*. This has historical reasons. See [Confusion about topology on CW complex: weak or final?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3234052)

Let us prove that if $X$ is endowed with the final topology, then all *subspaces* $X^n \subset X$ have their original toplogy:

1. Let $U \subset X^n$ be open in the subspace toplogy. Then $U = A \cap X^n$ with some open $A \subset X$. But by definition of the final topology $A \cap X^n$ is open in $X^n$ with its original toplogy.
2. Let $U = U_n \subset X^n$ be open in the original topology. Using the fact that each $X^{k-1}$ is a subspace of $X^k$, we can recursively construct open $U_k \subset X^k$, $k \ge n$, such that $U_{k+1} \cap X^k = U_k$. Moreover, for $k < n$ define $U_k = U_n \cap X^k$ which is open in $X^k$. By construction we have $U_k \cap X^m = U_k$ if $k \le m$ and $U_k \cap X^m = U_m$ if $k > m$. Then $A = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty U_k$ is open in $X$: In fact, $A \cap X_m = (\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty U_k) \cap X_m = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty U_k \cap X_m = \bigcup_{k=0}^m U_k \cup \bigcup_{k=m+1}^\infty U_m = U_m$ which is open in $X^m$. This also shows $A \cap X^n = U_n = U$, i.e $U$ is open in the subspace topology.

If the sequence $X^0, X^1, X^2,\ldots$ stabilizes, i.e. if we have $X = X^N$ for some $N$ (which is the same as $X^n = X^N$ for $n \ge N$), then there is no need to introduce a new topology on $X$ since $X^N$ already has one. The above proof shows nevertheless that $A \subset X$ is open iff $A \cap X^n$ is open in $X^n$ for all $n$. However, in that case it is trivial: If $A \cap X^n$ is open in $X^n$ for all, then $A = A \cap X = A \cap X^N$ is open in $X = X^N$. Conversely, if $A \subset X^N$ is open, then $A \cap X^n$ is open in $X^n$ for all $n \le N$ because $X^n$ is a subspace of $X^N$ and open in $X^n$ for all $n > N$ because $X^n = X^N$ and $A \cap X^n = A$.

Comment: My problem is that I can't see the triviality of that statement...  Could you please provide some hint as to why that statement is indeed true?

Comment: @PratikApshinge I added some material.

Comment: Thank you so much, this made everything very clear!