# Why is the weak topology not more widely defined?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, weak-topology

I first came across the concept of a weak topology (or initial topology) in the context of functional analysis. It is virtually unmentioned in such standard upper level undergraduate / first year graduate texts as Munkres *Topology* and Kelley *General Topology*. Yet it would seem to be a rather ubiquitous and useful concept for constructing important basic topologies.

For example, both the subspace topology and the product topology arise naturally as weak topologies. The latter viewpoint seems especially useful as the standard definition of the product topology to my mind has a somewhat clunky feel.

Given its apparent simplicity and usefulness, why does it not play a more central role in introductions to topology?

Comment: There is a more general concept of weak  topology  generated by a family of real valued functions on a set. (Or a family of functions with values in a  given topological space). Weak and weak^ toplogies in FA are just special cases of this.

Comment: By "weak" topology do you actually mean the "initial" topology? Anyway, perhaps you overestimate the "natural" aspect of the weak topology. I don't think many people think about subspace and product topologies in that way. Classical definitions seem more intuitive. Also while they arise in a somewhat similar manner, their properties are very different. And that's the weakest point of the weak topology (pun intended): the resulting properties depend heavily on the choice of the maps.

Comment: @freakish Yes, I thought "weak topology" and "initial topology" were synonyms. Is that wrong? Perhaps I should edit the question.

Comment: @DavidM some people do indeed treat them as synonyms. However nowadays the weak topology term is heavily related to the functional analysis. Often it denotes the specific case of the initial topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the concept of *weak topology* occurs in functional analysis: Given a topological vector space $X$, we can retopologize $X$ by giving it the initial topology induced by the family $X'$ of continuous linear functionals living on $X$.

Unfortunately the phrase "weak topology" is not standardized. In the context of CW-complexes it means something completely different: The letter "W" in "CW" stands for
*weak topology*, but here it is a suitable *final topology*. See the discussion in
[Confusion about topology on CW complex: weak or final?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3234052)

Thus "weak topology" and "initial topology" cannot be regarded as synonyms, the interpretation of "weak topology" depends on the context.

Nevertless, the concept of *initial topology* is quite useful and important. In my opinion it should be treated in good textbooks. However, in older literature (as Kelley and Munkres) it usually does not occur. I guess that thinking in *universal properties* is a modern approach; it was unusual to do that for a long time. Perhaps it is a matter of taste: The price for the modern aproach is a higher level of abstraction which is not really needed very frequently.