topological jargon confuses me - weak/strong topology and convergence
I am confused about certain terms in topology that are used frequently, and that I can not find a precise explanation for.
In this post somebody mentioned, that weak and strong are not used consistently in the literature, but at least they should be within each individual text.

Dual space: define the dual space of a space $X$ to be the set of all linear, continuous (wrt. to the norm topology $\tau_N$) functionals.


Weak topology: define the weak topology $\tau_W$ to be the weakest topology, such that all elements of the dual space remain continuous in this weak topology.

weak topology
Question 1: The term weak must mean that $\tau_W \subset \tau_N$, otherwise the definition would be irrelevant. Only when we remove open sets from $\tau_N$, we end up with potentially less continuous functions from $X$ to another set. Is this correct?
Question 2: From this realization we can also deduce, that in a weaker=smaller topology, more sequences converge, because there are less open sets in which the sequence members "have to be" to fulfill the property of convergence. Is this correct?
Question 3: Similarly, there are now more compact sets in $X$ when endowed with a weaker=smaller topology, as the open covers of the space are possibly easier to give rise to a finite subcover, I assume .. is this correct?
dual space
Consider the topological space $X$ with a given topology $\tau$. Suppose we know this space "has a comparatively strong convergence, which implies that there exist a lot of continuous functionals".
From above we know
$$\text{topology weak (=small) }\implies \text{ less continuous functions }$$
and
$$\text{topology weak (=small) }\implies \text{ more sequences converge }$$
Question 4: I am trying to make sense of the quote. What does "strong convergence" mean? Does it mean that the topology is strong, that we have less converging sequences, but more continuous function(al)s? This would explain the quote, but would still be strange, as strong convergence sounds like "lots of sequences converge", but the opposite is true.
Question 5: Another phrase that is used a lot is that functions are continuous "with respect to the norm convergence". Obviously it is clear that "continuity with respect to the norm topology" is meant, but why use the term convergence here? Is the reason, that on normed spaces, continuity and sequential continuity are equivalent?

The phrases "weak topology " and "strong topolgy" are used also in other contexts. Their interpretation has changed over the time. In my answer to   https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3234052 I gave a survey explaining the "old" interpretation. This corresponds to your Question 4 where are are suprised by the fact that in the strong topology there are less convergent sequences. In the old understanding "stronger" means "more limit points".

Thank you, i will take a look


Yes.Though sometimes nothing is lost. For example if $X$ is a normed space, then the dual of $(X,\tau_W)$ is the same as the dual of $(X,\tau_N)$.

Yes. Closures in a weaker topology are usually bigger. There are important exceptions to this in Functional Analysis: on a normed space, the weak closure of a convex set agrees with the norm closure.

Yes, there are more compact sets when you consider a weaker topology. This shows in the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem, that says that the closed unit ball of the dual of a normed space is compact in the weak$^*$-topology.

I cannot make sense of the quote as written. For starters, if $X$ is just a topological vector space, it is possible for the dual to consists of just the zero functional; this can happen even when $X$ is metric. When $X$ is normed, on the other hand, we have the Hahn-Banach theorem that guarantees the existence of lots and lots of continuous linear functionals.

While a topology is formally defined by giving the open sets (or sometimes a subbase), one can define a topology in terms of convergence. For instance in a metric space you first have a metric $d$, and then you define $x_j\to x$ to mean that $d(x_j,x)\to0$. Alternatively you can use the metric to define balls and use the balls to define the open sets. But the point is that it is often convenient to define a topology just in terms of  convergence of nets (sequences if the space is metric). In the particular case of topological vector spaces in functional analysis, all your observations are very pertinent; but one can simply define then weak convergence $x_j\xrightarrow[]{\rm weak} x$ to mean that $\varphi(x_j)\to\varphi(x)$ for all $\varphi\in X^*$. In this point of view you can see that the weak topology is weaker than the original topology because $\varphi$ is continuous, so if $x_j\to x$ then $x_j\xrightarrow[]{\rm weak} x$. In the case of a normed space you have $$|\varphi(x_j)-\varphi(x)|\leq \|\varphi\|\,\|x_j-x\|.$$



Thank you for your explanation!

Glad I could help!
